# How does std::map call value destructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, stdmap

I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class test{
   public:
   test() {
     cout << "calling test ctor " << endl;
   }

   ~test() {
      cout << "calling test dtor " << endl;
   }

   void callme(){
      cout << "call me " << endl;
   }
};

int main () {
   map<int, test> mp;
   mp[0].callme();
   mp[0].callme();
   return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is :

```
calling test ctor 
calling test dtor 
calling test dtor 
call me 
call me 
calling test dtor
```

I am little confused how std::map is handling test:: ctors and dtors here.

Before executing this code, my assumption was that mp[0].callme() would create a new `test` object and call `callme()` on that, and if we call mp[0].callme() again, then it should call test:: dtor (since we are replacing the key `0` here) and then test:: ctor to create a new `test` object so that it could call `callme()` on that. Obviously my assumption is wrong here because output doesn't match at all.

Could anyone please throw some light on this ?

**EDIT1**:

gcc --version = gcc (GCC) 5.1.1 20150422 (Red Hat 5.1.1-1)

**Command to compile:**

`g++ maps.cpp`

So, no flags with g++. Simple compile.

Comment: You forgot to define a copy constructor.

Comment: I am not sure how you got that output.  running the code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e05917741e4afef) gives the correct output.

Comment: Name the compiler and version.

Comment: Are you testing with optimizations turned off? Seems your compiler is creating a lot of intermediate copies. Add copy & move constructor definitions also to trace what's going on.

Comment: Where would it be making copies? `map` doesn't move things around internally like `vector` does...

Comment: If you want to match ctors and dtors, you need to print from *all* ctors.

Comment: Rule of five: monitor  all copy, move constructors, assignment operator and destructor

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'm getting same output as OP

Comment: @Barry perhaps `operator[]` makes a copy or two when unoptimized. I wouldn't know, it doesn't reoroduce on ideone.

Comment: @NathanOliver, C++14 gives me your output, and C++ 4.9.2 gives me OP's output

Comment: What do you mean by "are replacing the key"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I mean using the already existing key in the map.

Comment: Then what would it be destructing?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, I thought it would be destructing the object against the already existing key.

Comment: @pranavk that would be terrible. Normally you set up a map so you can look stuff up in it repeatedly. For map to throw away what it has when you try to look up element 0, that would be really strange.

Comment: How could it return a reference to an object it destroyed?

Comment: Ah,I am sorry. That is terrible indeed. I misthought. Kindly ignore.

Answer (score 2):

By compiling using the command `g++ maps.cpp`, you're invoking g++ in C++03 mode, which means it isn't able to use move semantics.

The relevant lines of the `map::operator[]` implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h#L481-L488)

```
    if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      __i = _M_t._M_emplace_hint_unique(__i, std::piecewise_construct,
                        std::tuple<const key_type&>(__k),
                        std::tuple<>());
#else
      __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
#endif
```

So prior to C++11, the `mapped_type` (`test` in your example) is default constructed to create a `value_type` (`pair<int const, test>` in your example). This is the initial call to the constructor.

The call to `insert` then has to copy the mapped type at least once when it inserts it into the internal storage for the `map`. Evidently, the libstdc++ implementation results in an additional copy somewhere, adding up to two copy constructions, and hence two matching destructor calls. If you add a copy constructor definition you'll see the number of destructor calls match the number of constructor calls.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74f98353d7e02bee)

Also, notice that by adding the `-std=c++11` flag, you avoid the intermediate copies. As seen in the code above, the implementation uses piecewise construction of the `pair` in that case to directly construct the `mapped_type` (and `key_type`) in the `map`'s internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your `operator[]` uses the following logic:

1. If the object doesn't exist, create it and then set it equal to a default-constructed object.
2. Return a reference to the object.

That is very strange behavior. The extra construction and assignment is not needed. The new object should just be default constructed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class test{
   public:
   test() {
     cout << "calling test ctor " << endl;
   }

   test(const test&) {
     cout << "calling copy ctor " << endl;
   }

//   test(test&&) {
//     cout << "calling move ctor " << endl;
//   }

   test& operator = (const test&) {
     cout << "calling copy assignment " << endl;
     return * this;
   }

//   test& operator = (test&&) {
//     cout << "calling move assignment " << endl;
//     return * this;
//   }

   ~test() {
      cout << "calling test dtor " << endl;
   }

   void callme(){
      cout << "call me " << endl;
   }
};

int main () {
   map<int, test> mp;
   mp[0].callme();
   mp[0].callme();
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled without C++11 gives:

```
calling test ctor 
calling copy ctor 
calling copy ctor 
calling test dtor 
calling test dtor 
call me 
call me 
calling test dtor
```

Having comments on move semantics removed and compiled with C++11:

```
calling test ctor 
call me 
call me 
calling test dtor
```

Both are compiled with g++ 4.8.4

Comment: More interesting output can be had by making the cout lines also print the address of the `test` objects involved.  Then you can see that in the no-C++11 mode, it creates a `test` on the stack, copies it elsewhere on the stack, and then copies it into the heap, before destroying the two stack copies.  This all happens within the implementation of `std::map::operator[]`, and even with `-O3`, which seems somewhat broken.